# Change a td date color with PHP

Tags: php, css, arrays

I have to change my color td's date_client depending of current date.
For example, if today is the birthday's client, this td s'date turns red (font, not background).

My HTML

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row) : ?>
      <tr id_client=<?php echo $row["id_client"]; ?>>
        <td><?php echo $row["id_client"]; ?></td>
        
        <td><?php echo $row["client_birth_date"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

My array
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpzwl.png

Since i am in a loop foreach, each birthdate is unique.

I have tried this in PHP.
PHP

```
 function date_color(){
      global $conn;
      $id_client = $_POST["id_client"];
      $client_date = $_POST["client_birth_date"];
      $calendar=$_POST["calendrier"];
    
      $calendar->date_format('Y-m-d'). $client_date->date_format('Y-m-d');
    
      if ($calendar==$client_date){
        echo "<font color='#FF0000'>$client_date</font>";
      }
        
    }
```

calendar is the date input in my screen.

I don't know how to do in JS neither. (the obstacle is how to get precisely the td's date birth)

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the database date with a variable containing todays date. If they match, apply a class to the `<td>`. Note: database date and todays date have to be in the same formate (Y-m-d).

```
  //create todays date once
$today = date('Y-m-d');

foreach ($rows as $row){
  $id=$row["id_client"];
  $birthday = $row["client_birth_date"];
  
    //create empty class
  $class = '';
    //compare birthday with today. If equal, set a class class
  if( $birthday == $today ){
    $class =' class="font_red"';
    }
  
    //output
  echo '<tr id=".$id.'">
          <td>'.$id.'</td>
          <td'.$class.'>'.$birthday.'</td>  //<-- apply class
        </tr>';
    }
```

And css

```
.font_red{
  color: red;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry michel but your apply this in HTML part no ? 
I tried it to insert in but no result.
I done too with a function in my php file but, i don't understand how with "echo" , we can apply a style to the good td.
 

Sorry , i am a novice...

Comment: PHP only outputs text and HTML is nothing more than text in a special format (with tags). So what you call the _HTML part_  is just PHP outputting text in HTML format.  `echo` tells PHP to output text. `echo "<td>text</td>"` does exactly the same as  `?> <td>text</td> <?php`

Comment: Read [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) and [string operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to get some more background on this.

Comment: Yes i did it ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My code now :

```
 $today = date('Y-m-d');
foreach ($rows as $row) :
    
    $birthday = $row["birthday"];

    $HowManyWeeks = date('W', strtotime($today)) - date('W', strtotime($birthday));

    $class = '';

    //birthday =
    if ($birthday == $today) {
      $class = ' class="font_red"';
    }
    //birthday= yellow or orange else black
    elseif ($HowManyWeeks == 1) {
      $class = ' class="font_yellow"';
    } elseif ($HowManyWeeks == -1) {
      $class = ' class="font_orange"';
    } else {
      $class = ' class="font_black"';
    }
  ?>
    <td id="id"><?php echo $row["id_client"]; ?></td>
    <td id="nom"><?php echo $row["nom_client"]; ?></td>
    <td id="prenom"><?php echo $row["prenom_client"]; ?></td>
    <?php echo  '<td id="date"'  . $class  . '>' . $row["birthday"] . ' </td>'; ?>
```